# form's save button, how to explain?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a little problem with built-in cakephp post form and I am unable to figure out how the `echo $form->end('Save');` at the end of the source code works after i click the save button. I hope someone could help me explain something about it so that I can further process the entered information in this form. Thank you so much,....

```
<?php

if(isset($passwordItem))
{
    echo $form->create(null,array('url' => '/user/passwordchange/'.$passwordItem['User']['id']));
}
?>
<h1>Change your password</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="220px">Enter new password</td>
        <td><input type="password" size="33" name="newpassword"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Confirm new password</td>
        <td><input type="password" size="33" name="newPasswordConfirm"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $form->end('Save');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes a submit button with the appropriate options. As for what happens after the data is submitted, I think you should look at the following:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1384/Creating-Forms

Answer (score 0):

as a side note:

if you want to make submit button your own way in pure html string, you can do this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" ... more_html_here >';
echo $form->end();//this will output only closing </form> tag
```